# TextView moving out of screen in RTL Layout in RelativeLayout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text view inside a RelativeLayout. It's working fine in LTR layout. But when I change it to RTL the view inside a RelativeLayout moves out of visible screen. I was checking it in Layout inspector and I could see it being out of the screen visible area. The view is visible but it's not in the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_empty"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/data_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:minHeight="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/refresh" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/progressbar_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/progressbar_height"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

refresh_text is the TextView which is moving out of the visible region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is with relative layout  use ConstraintLayout
try this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_empty"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/data_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:minHeight="40dp">

        <TextView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/refresh" />

        <ProgressBar
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/progressbar_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/progressbar_height"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```